# If values exist in list, put them at the back of the list in Python

Tags: python, list, performance

I have a list with values and a list with some given numbers:

```
my_list = [1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 10]
my_numbers = [2, 3, 4]
```

Now I want to know if the values in `my_numbers` exist in `my_list` and, if so, put the matching value(s) to the back of `my_list`. I can do this for example like this:

```
for number in my_numbers:
    if number in my_list:
        my_list.remove(number)
        my_list.append(number)
```

**Specifics:**

- I can be certain that there are no duplicates within neither of the lists due to my program setup.
- The order of which the matching numbers in `my_numbers` are put in the back of `my_list` does **not** matter.

**Question:** Can I do this more efficiently performance wise?

Comment: I am sorry, I don't get why you mean. The sample code works fine. And I don't get the -1 on my question either, isn't it well explained? And how can I do this instead?

Comment: @TomKarzes The list `my_list` is not iterated over. There is only an `in` check for this list in each loop iteration over the other list, `my_numbers`, so the modification is safe (even if not very good performance-wise).

Comment: @Frank, My question is if there is a more efficient way, so do you have a suggestion? :)

Comment: You want to sort your list based on whether the value exists in another list? Then you can *sort* it based on that criterion: `my_numbers.sort(key=lambda i: i in my_list)` (maybe `reversed=True` as well, I can never remember off the top of my head which way that'll sort…). You can make that more efficient by making `my_list` a `set`. This would be a reasonable compromise between efficiency and expressiveness. You can probably come up with even more efficient algorithms, but at that point the question is whether that's worth it.

Comment: @Frank Oops, you're right thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is this: rebuild the list `my_list` from two parts:

- the items that are not in `my_numbers`
- the items that are in `my_numbers`

Note that I would suggest to use a `set` for the lookup. A membership test for a `set` is `O(1)` (constant time), whereas such a test for a `list` is `O(n)`, where `n` is the length of the list.

This means that the total runtime of the code below is `O(max(m,n))`, where m, n are the lengths of the lists. Your original solution was more like `O(m*n)`, which is much slower if either of the lists is large.

```py
my_numbers_set = set(my_numbers)

my_list = [x for x in my_list if x not in my_numbers_set] + \
          [x for x in my_list if x in my_numbers_set]
```

Comment: Thanks, is this really faster than remove and put to back of an existing list though? It feels to me as if modifying an existing list is faster than creating 2 new list and concat them together :)

Comment: No, it's not, because removing an item from a list takes O(n) time if the item is somewhere in the middle. Note that all items *behind* the removed item need to be moved one position towards the front. This can be a real issue if done frequently for long lists.

Comment: I see, thank you for the answer. I will try and see if speeds up my code